# Compressing profiles with a large number of dimensions

Tags: machine-learning, amazon-ml

I 'think' [this](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/8029/online-incremental-unsupervised-dimensionality-reduction-for-use-with-classifica) is a related question, but not sure how to apply it.

I'm trying to build out a very crude recommendation system using Amazon ML, Facebook likes, and historical actions.

So lets say we have a number of users within a system that promotes products within several categories. To better predict which categories of items to present to the user, we will consider their past interactions with specific items, and the past interactions of other users who share a similar profile. The profile consisting of basically the users Facebook likes data and some demographic info.

I'm unsure of how to distill the Facebook likes data in a way that lets me make meaningful comparisons between users.

I'm sure its obvious, but I'm completely new to machine learning, and data science in general. I'm currently limited to the capabilities of Amazon ML. Let me know if the question needs more clarification, constructive criticism is appreciated.

Edit:
As @liangjy pointed out, the solution to the recommendation system in general will be to use the collaborative filtering technique. This is most useful when their is sufficient data to link users based on their individual actions. Because we do not have enough/any data on new users, we are trying to use additional data (Facebook likes in this case) to help create that initial link. Where I'm stuck at is the vast number of profile/sites any one user may have liked. We could be comparing the likes of one user against tens of thousands of possibilities the rest of the users have presented. What is the best way to make this disparate data into something manageable?

I've considered taking a subset of users and pulling the top n sites (1,000?) from each demographic groups (age/gender). Then compare all other users to this base set, and create sub-groups based on their relationships to those sites. However, something about this approach feels like it would be skewed. I'm not sure what, but I'm pretty sure I won't get the results I'm looking for.

Comment: Why the downvote? I don't really mind it, but at least tell me why so I can improve the question.

Comment: It's a young site.  People coming from larger sites (StackOverflow) that can afford to drive off new users haven't realized that upvotes and polite responses are far more important to the budding community than rigid adherence to the posting rules (which I'm assuming you broke one of, hence the downvote).

Comment: Don't worry your question is kind of very new to me so I can't answer but +1 for a nice question

Answer (score 0):

This seems similar to the collaborative filtering problem of assigning ratings to movies based on similar users and past reviews: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collaborative_filtering. The essence of this approach is to find a low-rank factorization of the matrix of ratings, where each user has one rating for each movie/product, and some of the ratings are unseen.

Comment: Yes, this is the general approach I'm taking. I'll edit the question to maybe provide better description of the question.